# ¿Las oraciones de interjección deben llevar mayúscula?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

Según entiendo una de las reglas más basicas es que toda oración inicia con mayuscula.

Sin embargo, en torno a las oraciones formadas con interjecciones he encontrado que a veces inician con minúscula y otras veces con mayúscula.

Incluso en el mismo [artículo de wikipedia acerca de interjecciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjecci%C3%B3n) aparece de ambas formas en el mismo articulo.  (**Parrafo 1**:  "¡ay!" , "¡zas!"  y **Parrafo 2**: ¡Alto! , "¡Ay!" , "¡Eh!" , etc)

¿Son estos simples errores o hay alguna regla especial que rige cuando una interjección debe llevar mayúscula y cuando no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una interjección debe escribirse comenzando por mayúscula si con ella comienza una frase, o si constituye en sí una frase independiente. Por ejemplo:

- Te dije que hicieras la compra. ¡Ay! Qué mala memoria tienes.
- No puede entrar ahí. ¡Alto! Deténgase inmediatamente.

Pero si la interjección forma parte de una frase, es decir, si antes de ella no tenemos un punto, entonces deberá ir en minúscula, como en estos casos:

- Qué mala suerte, ¡ay!
- Qué día tan lluvioso, ¿eh?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!